can i use different value capacitors in parallel to get a bigger value capacitance?
i am recapping an old stereo system, where i came across a 15uf 63v capacitor connected to supply pin (pin 5 of tda2030) and ground.So,can i use 10uf/63v and 4.7uf/63v in parallel to achieve close to 15uf or should i use 6.8uf/63v x 2 in parallel to achieve slightly less than 15uf ?

This sounds like a supply decoupling capacitor, where the tolerances will be quite loose. A little under should be OK, a lot over will be just fine. Either of your suggestions ought to be OK. You could also use 2 x 10 uF if you have the space, and want to err on the very safe side.
